# Is it OK to manually charge a single cell of a 2 cell LIPO battery?

Tags: lipo

I have a 2 cell LiPo battery and my project involves charging it from a rectified and regulated voltage source. My question is, is it OK if I charge only a single one of these cells instead of both? Or should I connect my 3.7V output into both cells?

Comment: It is not a good practice to charge 1 at a time as they become unbalanced and if discharged unless to balance or monitor each cell, underchange cannot be detected. Nor is it wise to switch discharged cells in parallel to charge them unless identical voltage unless current limited.

Comment: Do you mean 'undercharge'? It may not be good practice but if I can use a 2 cell LiPo battery as a single cell one, then it should be OK to do, no?

Comment: I see you mean to also use in parallel use only. OK  But be conservative for cutoff and use 10% CC or more for cutoff as they may not be come charged at the same time.